# Pandas: Subtract timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I grouped a dataframe `test_df2` by frequency `'B'` (by business day, so each name of the group is the date of that day at 00:00) and am now looping over the groups to calculate timestamp differences and save them in the dict `grouped_bins`. The data in the original dataframe and the groups looks like this:

|  | timestamp | status | externalId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-05-11 13:06:05.922 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 2020-05-11 13:14:29.759 | 10 | 1 |
| 8 | 2020-05-11 13:16:09.147 | 1 | 2 |
| 16 | 2020-05-11 13:19:08.641 | 10 | 2 |

What I want is to calculate the difference between each row's `timestamp`, for example of rows `7` and `0`, since they have the same `externalId`.

What I did for that purpose is the following.

```
# Group function. Dataframes are saved in a dict.
def groupDataWithFrequency(self, dataFrameLabel: str, groupKey: str, frequency: str):
    '''Group time series by frequency. Starts at the beginning of the data frame.'''
    print(f"Binning {dataFrameLabel} data with frequency {frequency}")
    if (isinstance(groupKey, str)):
        return self.dataDict[dataFrameLabel].groupby(pd.Grouper(key=groupKey, freq=frequency, origin="start"))

grouped_jobstates = groupDataWithFrequency("jobStatus", "timestamp", frequency)
```

After grouping, I loop over each group (to maintain the day) and try to calculate the difference between the timestamos, which is where it goes wrong.

```
grouped_bins = {}

def jobStatusPRAggregator(data, name):
    if (data["status"] == 1):

        # Find corresponding element in original dataframe
        correspondingStatus = test_df2.loc[(test_df2["externalId"] == data["externalId"]) & (test_df2["timestamp"] != data["timestamp"])]

        # Calculate time difference
        time = correspondingStatus["timestamp"] - data["timestamp"]

        # some prints:
        print(type(time))
        # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> --> Why is this a series?

        print(time.array[0])
        # 0 days 00:08:23.837000 --> This looks correct, I think?

        print(time)
        # 7   0 days 00:08:23.837000
        # Name: timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
    
        # Check if element exists in dict
        elem = next((x for x in grouped_bins if ((x["startDate"] == name) ("productiveTime" in x))), None)
      
        # If does not exist yet, add to dict
        if elem is None:
            grouped_bins.append( {"startDate": name, "productiveTime": time })
        else:
            elem["productiveTime"] = elem["productiveTime"]
            # See below for problem

# Loop over groups
for name, group in grouped_jobstates:
    group.apply(jobStatusPRAggregator, args=(name,), axis=1)
```

The problem I face is the following. The element in the dict (`elem`) looks like this in the end:

```
{'startDate': Timestamp('2020-05-11 00:00:00', freq='B'), 'productiveTime': 0      NaT
7      NaT
8      NaT
16     NaT
17     NaT
        ..
1090   NaT
1091   NaT
1099   NaT
1100   NaT
1107   NaT
Name: timestamp, Length: 254, dtype: timedelta64[ns]}
```

What I want is something like this:

```
{'startDate': Timestamp('2020-05-11 00:00:00', freq='B'), 'productiveTime': 2 Days 12 hours 39 minutes 29 seconds
Name: timestamp, Length: 254, dtype: timedelta64[ns]}
```

Though I am open to suggestions on how to store time durations in Python/Pandas.

I am also open to suggestions regarding the loop itself.

Comment: Hard to say from what you provide above, but is the type of the timestamp column data a string?  If so, you need to convert it to a datetime object before performing operations on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain timestamp differences between consecutive rows of the same `externalId`, you should be able to simply write, for example:

```py
df2 = df.assign(delta=df.groupby('externalId')['timestamp'].diff())
```

On the example you give:

```py
>>> df2
                 timestamp  status  externalId                  delta
0  2020-05-11 13:06:05.922       1           1                    NaT
7  2020-05-11 13:14:29.759      10           1 0 days 00:08:23.837000
8  2020-05-11 13:16:09.147       1           2                    NaT
16 2020-05-11 13:19:08.641      10           2 0 days 00:02:59.494000
```

If your timestamps are not actually of type `Timestamp` yet, then you can convert them into it first:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

Comment: Hi Pierre. Do you know how to compute the timestamp differences between NON-consecutive rows? (for example, the `timestamp difference` between the `last time` and the `first time` for each Id?

Comment: sure, something along the line of `gbt = df.groupby('externalId')['timestamp']` and then `gbt.max() - gbt.min()` (maximum duration span) or `gbt.last() - gbt.first()`. Note, that's the gist, haven't actually tried it, but should be close enough.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your timestamp strings to a datetime object:

```
import datetime
datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, datetime_format)
```

Then from your code above:

```
# Calculate time difference
time1 = datetime.strptime(correspondingStatus["timestamp"], datetime_format)
time2 = datetime.strptime(data["timestamp"], datetime_format)
time = time1 - time2
```